# how can i specify the return type for asyncRabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceiveAsType() at run time?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, java-16

i've been struggeling with the following code. and am not sure how to deserialize it or even pass the correct type at run time.

the code is:

```
 @Override
    public <T, R> R sendAsync(T payload, String routingKey, String exchangeName) {
       
        ListenableFuture<R> listenableFuture =
                asyncRabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceiveAsType(
                        exchangeName,
                        routingKey,
                        payload,
                        new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {
                        }
                );

        try {

            return listenableFuture.get();

        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            LOGGER.error(" [x] Cannot get response.", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

let us say that am just calling the method like the following

```
SaveImageResponse response = backendClient.sendAsync( new SaveImageRequest(createQRRequest.getOwner(), qr), RabbitConstants.CREATE_QR_IMAGE_KEY, RabbitConstants.CDN_EXCHANGE);
```

while the pojo is the following:

```
public class SaveImageResponse {
    private String id;
    private String message;

    public SaveImageResponse() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SaveImageResponse{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", message='" + message + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

the current code is throwing the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class dev.yafatek.qr.api.responses.SaveImageResponse (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; dev.yafatek.qr.api.responses.SaveImageResponse is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

thanks in advance

SOLUTION:

so I ended up using the following:

```
@Override
    public <T, R> R sendAsync(T payload, String routingKey, String exchangeName, Class<R> clazz) {

        ListenableFuture<R> listenableFuture =
                asyncRabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceiveAsType(
                        exchangeName,
                        routingKey,
                        payload,
                        new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {
                        }
                );

        try {
            return objectMapper.convertValue(listenableFuture.get(), clazz);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            LOGGER.error(" [x] Cannot get response.", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

by using the object mapper and pass the actual type when call the method using

```
Class<POJO> clazz
```

to use the above code :

```
WebsiteInfoResponse websiteInfoResponse = backendClient.sendAsync(new GetWebsiteInfoReq(createBusinessDetailsRequest.getWebsiteUrlId()), RabbitConstants.GET_WEBSITE_INFO_KEY, RabbitConstants.QR_EXCHANGE, WebsiteInfoResponse.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The whole reason for `ParameterizedTypeReference<Foo>` is to tell the converter you want a `Foo`; this has to be resolved at compile time for the method; you can't call `sendAsync()` to receive different types.

Providing no generic type means it will convert to `Object` (usually a map).

Even `new ParameterizedTypeReference<R>() { }` won't work because `R` is not resolved at compile time for the generic type (of the `sendAsync()` method).

You have to do the conversion yourself.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So69299112Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So69299112Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    MessageConverter converter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Bean
    AsyncRabbitTemplate template(RabbitTemplate template) {
        template.setMessageConverter(new SimpleMessageConverter());
        return new AsyncRabbitTemplate(template);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(Service service) {
        return args -> {
            byte[] response = service.sendAsync("bar", "foo", "");
            Foo foo = this.mapper.readerFor(Foo.class).readValue(response);
            System.out.println(foo);
        };
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "foo")
    public Foo listen(String in) {
        return new Foo(in);
    }

    public static class Foo {

        String foo;

        public Foo() {
        }

        public Foo(String foo) {
            this.foo = foo;
        }

        public String getFoo() {
            return this.foo;
        }

        public void setFoo(String foo) {
            this.foo = foo;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Foo [foo=" + this.foo + "]";
        }

    }

}

@Component
class Service {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Service.class);

    AsyncRabbitTemplate asyncRabbitTemplate;

    public Service(AsyncRabbitTemplate asyncRabbitTemplate) {
        this.asyncRabbitTemplate = asyncRabbitTemplate;
    }

    public byte[] sendAsync(Object payload, String routingKey, String exchangeName) {

        ListenableFuture<byte[]> listenableFuture = asyncRabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(
                exchangeName,
                routingKey,
                payload);

        try {

            return listenableFuture.get();

        }
        catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            LOGGER.error(" [x] Cannot get response.", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: sounds cool, thanks for sharing

Comment: thanks for inspiring me, please check the solution attached to my question. regards